# In Ionic with React, isHistory.push changes the urs but does not render page

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, react-router, ionic5

In my Ionic app, I have a login screen and a dashboard screen.

When log in succeeds in Login.tsx, a user is created, then `console.log("Go to dashboard")` runs, followed by `history.push("/dashboard")`, which should show the Dashboard. The problem is that `history.push` changes the url to /dashboard but the dashboard page is not shown and I only still see the login view, even though `"Stay in Dashboard"` is printed in the console. If I then refresh the page, the correct Dashboard view is shown.

How do I fix this? Is this because Ionic cannot use isHistory? I also tried using `import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";` in Login screen instead of getting history from props with the same result. What is the correct way to change route in Ionic-React?

App.tsx

```js
...
const App: React.FC = () => (
  <IonApp>
    <IonReactRouter>
      <IonRouterOutlet>
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route exact path="/dashboard"><Dashboard /></Route>
        <Route exact path="/"><Redirect to="/login" /></Route>
      </IonRouterOutlet>
    </IonReactRouter>
  </IonApp>
);
```

Login.tsx

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth";
import { auth } from "../config/firebase";

const Login: React.FC<RouteComponentProps> = ({ history }) => {
  // const history = useHistory();
  const [ email, setEmail ] = useState<string>("");
  const [ password, setPassword ] = useState<string>("");
  const [ user, loading, error ] = useAuthState(auth);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loading) { return; }
    if (user) {
      console.log("Go to dashboard")
      history.push("/dashboard");
    }
  }, [user, loading]);

  const handleCredentials = () => {
    // log in
  }

  return (
    <IonPage className="login-page">
      <IonContent fullscreen className="ion-padding ion-text-center">
        <IonGrid>
          <IonRow>
            <IonCol>
              <IonItem>
                <IonLabel position="floating"> Email</IonLabel>
                <IonInput
                  type="email"
                  value={email}
                  onIonChange={(e) => setEmail(e.detail.value!)}
                  placeholder="Email Address"
                ></IonInput>
              </IonItem>
            </IonCol>
          </IonRow>
          <IonRow>
            <IonCol>
            <IonItem>
              <IonLabel position="floating"> Password</IonLabel>
              <IonInput
                type="password"
                value={password}
                onIonChange={(e) => setPassword(e.detail.value!)}
                placeholder="Password"
              ></IonInput>
            </IonItem>
            </IonCol>
          </IonRow>
          <IonRow>
            <IonCol>
              <IonButton className="login__btn" expand="block" onClick={handleCredentials}>Login</IonButton>
            </IonCol>
          </IonRow>
        </IonGrid>
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

Dashboard.tsx

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { RouteComponentProps } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth";
import { auth } from "../config/firebase";

const Login: React.FC<RouteComponentProps> = ({ history }) => {
  const [user, loading, error] = useAuthState(auth);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (loading) { return; }
    if (!user) {
      console.log("Go to log in");
      return history.push("/login");
    }
    console.log("Stay in Dashboard");
  }, [user, loading]);
  return (
    <div className="dashboard">
      <div className="dashboard__container">
        Logged in
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Dashboard;
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer here: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/20707

Simply surround your tags with `<IonPage>` and the redirect works. In my case, I added 2 them into Dashboard and now `history.push` works as expected.

```js
    <IonPage>
      <IonContent fullscreen>
        <div className="dashboard">
          <div className="dashboard__container">
            Logged in as
            <div>{name}</div>
            <div>{user?.email}</div>
            <button className="dashboard__btn" onClick={logout}>
              Logout
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
```

Comment: for every page in ionic when using ionic router you have to use the <ion-page> tag or it will not work... I also strongly suggest that you also use the IonContent tag. FInally as some who seems to be starting with Ionic I suggest you start with the templates since the patterns are included already and it will save you time when starting out

Comment: wasted 1 day trying to solve this and this was exactly my issue.  I was using window.location.replace as a workaround

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issues in Ionic apps with routing before. One way I was able to resolve them is to render the routes additionally into the `Switch` component.

See [Switches in IonRouterOutlet](https://ionicframework.com/docs/react/navigation#switches-in-ionrouteroutlet):

> Since `IonRouterOutlet` takes over the job in determining which routes
> get rendered, using a `Switch` from React Router has no effect when
> used inside of an `IonRouterOutlet`. Switches still function as
> expected when used outside an `IonRouterOutlet`.

I cannot confirm this is the absolute "correct way", but is has worked for me in past projects when working around some of the Ionic React framework flakiness.

Example:

```
import { Redirect, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const App: React.FC = () => (
  <IonApp>
    <IonReactRouter>
      <IonRouterOutlet>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
          <Redirect to="/login" />
        </Switch>
      </IonRouterOutlet>
    </IonReactRouter>
  </IonApp>
);
```

Comment: @AaronSaunders I know what the Ionic docs say, I'm just saying that to solve some edge cases that *I've* had to still use the `Switch` component so `react-router-dom` could match the correct route. It *shouldn't* have any effect, but yet it does. I've a lot more experience and trust in `react-router` to do the correct expected routing behavior than the React Ionic components that seem a bit flaky at times.

Comment: @AaronSaunders Ah, I see, your comment wasn't directed to me, per se, but to a general audience. I've updated my answer to incorporate the documentation. Thanks.

Comment: Yep!!  To help folks who are not as knowledgeable and just cut and paste